# Problems with optimx for NLS logistic regression

Tags: r, optimization, logistic-regression

I am trying to estimate some parameters for a function based on historical data (y). This is a logistic regression with asynchronous updating (delta).

This is the system in question:

[image: funcs]

Where (for our purposes) X[t] = y[t], n2 is formulated as (1-n1) and phi1 and phi2 are formulated as phi1+deltaphi (as phi2>phi1), u[t] is an implicit error term captured by y_hat.

The data (log values):

```
y <- c(-0.083522212, -0.080744273, -0.098003453, -0.090994700, -0.105010991, -0.112070623, -0.115681762, -0.143194134, -0.146458642, -0.139691305, -0.128929970, -0.118047088, -0.095065509, -0.082399946, -0.100997872, -0.092699501, -0.082550517, -0.050470001, 0.030390893,  0.131429122,  0.180958369,  0.212374498,  0.223668346,  0.226461144,  0.209141361,  0.195377626,  0.178487458,
0.201981948,  0.233653604,  0.245221474,  0.227886405,  0.141274238,  0.046683795, -0.047819717, -0.112630561, -0.203788442, -0.238529171, -0.211924261, -0.233738086, -0.241872522, -0.238041656, -0.230753558, -0.242931741, -0.231894162, -0.243119603, -0.233052377, -0.230820606, -0.225594126, -0.232095554, -0.244800121, -0.252265025, -0.241778694, -0.227898251, -0.242656156, -0.229516117, -0.216082812, -0.220941314, -0.211800617, -0.183642284, -0.165779424, -0.159285263, -0.147407410, -0.138607996, -0.130455753, -0.094857132, -0.039392141, -0.003361144,  0.076381508,  0.101627405,  0.103042608,  0.096997308,  0.100308333, 0.098658702,  0.083952591,  0.077534743,  0.064491677,  0.056002466,  0.082643906,  0.080460147,  0.090688462)
```

Parameters for estimation:

```
phi1, deltaphi, beta, delta
```

Other stuff:

```
T <- 80
y_hat <- mat.or.vec(nr = T, nc = 1)
R = 1.019656
alpha_bar = 0 
n1 = mat.or.vec(nr = T, nc = 1)
```

Function:

```
f <- function(t, phi1, deltaphi, beta, delta, R, alpha_bar, y) {
  n1[t] <<- (delta*n1[t-1])+(1-delta)*(1/(1+exp(-beta*((y[t-1]+alpha_bar-R*y[t-2])*((-deltaphi))*y[t-3]))))
  y_hat = (((n1[t]*phi1+(1-n1[t])*(phi1+deltaphi))/((R+alpha_bar)))*y[t-1])
return((y[t]-y_hat)^2) 
}
func <- function(par) sum(sapply(4:T,f, par[1],par[2], par[3],par[4], R, alpha_bar, y)) 

fit <- optimx(c(0.9, 1.05, 0.05, 0.6),
              method = "nlm",
              func,
              hessian = TRUE)
```

I think n1 is the problem here, I've tried a bunch of tricks to get it comply as it is a recursive variable with no starting point, hence the superoperator. I've had some luck, but the function always collapses on me so I think the function may be misspecified in some way. There are some constraints on beta and delta - beta should be positive nonzero and delta should be between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get some answers with different optimizers (but not with `nlm`); it also does indeed look like your objective function might be overspecified, which different optimizers will handle differently ... I tried to simplify the objective function a little bit.

### set up constants

```
maxT <- 80
R <- 1.019656
alpha_bar <- 0
```

### prediction function

I used `with(as.list(par) ...)` to avoid having to unpack the parameter vector. This does make debugging a little harder, and does force us to use `<<-` within the expression ...

```
predfun <- function(par) {
    y_hat <- n1 <- numeric(maxT)  ## pre-allocate vectors
    with(as.list(par), {
        for (t in (4:maxT)) {
            n1[t] <<- (delta*n1[t-1])+(1-delta)*
                (1/(1+exp(-beta*((y[t-1]+alpha_bar-R*y[t-2])*
                                 ((-deltaphi))*y[t-3]))))
            y_hat[t] <<- (((n1[t]*phi1+(1-n1[t])*(phi1+deltaphi))/
                           ((R+alpha_bar)))*y[t-1])
        }
    })
    return(y_hat)
}
```

### objective function

```
func <- function(par) {
    return(sum((y[4:maxT]-predfun(par)[4:maxT])^2))
}
```

### optimization

```
p0 <- c(phi1=0.9, deltaphi=1.05, beta=0.05, delta=0.6)
func(p0)  ## check to make sure the function works for starting values
library(optimx)
fit <- optimx(par=p0,
              method = c("Nelder-Mead","BFGS","nlm"),
              func,
              hessian = TRUE)
```

### results

```
                  phi1 deltaphi     beta       delta         value fevals
Nelder-Mead -0.4967063 3.026097 6.227032 -0.16820934  7.546323e-02    265
BFGS        -0.4462906 2.903375 2.554713 -0.01802873  7.922255e-02    110
nlm                 NA       NA       NA          NA 8.988466e+307     NA
            gevals niter convcode  kkt1  kkt2 xtime
Nelder-Mead     NA    NA        0  TRUE  TRUE 0.143
BFGS           100    NA        1 FALSE FALSE 0.494
nlm             NA    NA     9999    NA    NA 0.001
```

nlm gives all-NA values; BFGS fails both KKT criteria; Nelder-Mead appears OK.  Nelder-Mead and BFGS give moderately different parameter estimates, although both give apparently small SSQ.

```
cc <- coef(fit)
plot(y)
lines(predfun(cc["Nelder-Mead",]), col=2)
lines(predfun(cc["BFGS",]), col=4)
```

The fitted lines are (almost) indistinguishable.

[image]

### transformed parameters

If you want to fit the parameters on a transformed scale, you would provide the initial parameters to your optimization function on the transformed scale, e.g.

```
p0 <- c(phi1=0.9, deltaphi=1.05, log_beta=log(0.05), logit_delta=qlogis(0.6))
```

Then in your objective function, back-transform them before using them:

```
predfun <- function(par) {
    y_hat <- n1 <- numeric(maxT)  ## pre-allocate vectors
    with(as.list(par), {
       delta <- plogis(logit_delta)
       beta <- exp(log_beta)
       ### ... then the rest of your objective function ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer professor! I apologize, in my original post I failed to mention some constraints, which I have now edited into the post. Beta should be positive nonzero (or it cancels out the term), and delta should be between 0 and 1 (but again, not =1). Using these constraints I can coax the function towards some favorable results, but the fit seems to suffer quite heavily.

Comment: You can use `L-BFGS-B` to impose box constraints, or estimate the parameters on transformed scales (log scale for Beta, log-odds (plogis/qlogis) scale for delta)

Comment: After some further consideration, I have managed to achieve a very favorable fit by using nlsLM as opposed to optimx, and as I observed conditional heteroskedasticity in the residuals, performing a second weighted regression. Your adjustments to the objective function put me on the right path. Thank you!

Comment: The transformed scales are actually quite interesting, how would one go about doing that? If I'm understanding the plogis function correctly, I can just replace the parameters with plogis(delta,log.p=TRUE) and log(beta). However, when I do this, I seem to get decent results with regards to the fitted data, but the standard error is extremely high. Do you have any insight?